# Using Numeral.js from HTML in Aurelia

Tags: html, aurelia, numeral.js

I have the following working Aurelia code:

```js
total = 9000;
```

```html
<div class="row pt-2">
  <div class="col-10 text-right">Amount is</div>
  <div class="col-2 text-right">${total}</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is use the [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) library in HTML to format the total variable from 9000 to 9000.00. This is what I have tried:

```js
total = 9000;
```

```html
<div class="row pt-2">
  <div class="col-10 text-right">Amount is</div>
  <div class="col-2 text-right">${numeral(${total}).format('0.00')}</div>
</div>
```

and the following:

```js
total = 9000;
```

```html
<div class="row pt-2">
  <div class="col-10 text-right">Amount is</div>
  <div class="col-2 text-right">numeral(${total}).format('0.00')</div>
</div>
```

but unfortunately, none have worked. I tried using the Numeral library in TypeScript and it works fine. I need this on the HTML though.
I'm super responsive so don't hesitate to ask any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a value converter to wrap the call to numeral.

This is what your value converter will look like. You'll have to add the correct import statement to the file though.

```
import numeral from 'numeral';

export class CurrencyFormatValueConverter {
  toView(value, format = '0.00') {
    return numeral(value).format(format);
  }
}
```

Then you'll need to load the value converter in to your view using a require element.

```
<require from="./path/to/file'></require>
```

Then you can use it in your view.

```
<div class="row pt-2">
  <div class="col-10 text-right">Amount is</div>
  <div class="col-2 text-right">${total | numeral }</div>
</div>
```

or you can pass in a custom format as a parameter to override the default:

```
<div class="row pt-2">
  <div class="col-10 text-right">Amount is</div>
  <div class="col-2 text-right">${total | numeral:'($0,0.00)' }</div>
</div>
```

Incidentally, you should give our documentation a look, as it actually includes this exact value converter as one of its examples: https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/value-converters#value-converters

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I thought it was a one liner. At this point do you recommend just doing the conversion in TypeScript and then passing it as a string to HTML?

Comment: @sbattoh Ashley's approach is absolutely the right way to approach this in any actual application. You probably don't want to touch the value of total, and a value converter is a much better approach, but I can't make that decision for you. Alternatively, you can assign numeral to your view-model, `this.numeral = numeral`, to make your original markup work. This is usually not the right approach, though.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis thank you so much for your input. I guess sometimes the best answer is not always the one liner. Also, why do you think that the this.numeral = numeral approach is not the greatest? I'm fairly new to Aurelia

Comment: It isn't idiomatic Aurelia. It also won't be reusable across multiple pages/views in your application. Using a Value Converter gives you the reusability of componentization, and the added perk of "doing it the Aurelia way." Finally, `${numeral(${total}).format('0.00')}` isn't valid Aurelia syntax. You'd have to use `${numeral(total).format('0.00')}`. But still, don't do it that way.

Comment: ^ This. The only time I would use this strategy is if I was creating a reproduction for an issue on GitHub.